# displaying the home page in the user end

Tags: joomla1.7

I am using Joomla 1.7. Whenever I am trying to access the site it says 404-article not found. I have tried with all the available templates in the template manager.

Can you suggest a solution.

Pushan

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have enabled SEF Urls but not renamed htaccess.txt to .htaccess - or perhaps your server doesn't support mod_rewrite.

Either rename the file or switch to a different SEF url scheme - without mod_rewrite, orturn off Sef urls altogether.